# La clase no es compatible con agregaciones (o el objeto de la clase es remoto) (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040110 (CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION))

Tags: ssms

En el PC que desarrollo tiene un SO Windows 10, instalé hace algún tiempo VS2013, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express y SQL Server Management Studio (por temas de clientes que trabajan con esta versión de la DB).

Estoy tratando de generar una consulta a una tabla o de modificar la estructura de alguna tabla y me aparece el error de la imagen adjunta (aclaro, todo estaba funcionando bien, hasta hoy).

Este error aparece apenas presiono el botón Nueva Consulta, o si voy a modificar la tabla al dar clic derecho sobre ella.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error presentado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Rafael, bienvenido a Stack Overflow. ¿Podrías poner el código de la consulta para poder depurar mejor el error?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor indica todos los elementos necesarios para poder reproducir tu problema y así ayudarte de una mejor manera.

Comment: Según una búsqueda rápida en Google (copiando exactamente el título de tu pregunta), lo que tienes que hacer es desinstalar e instalar de nuevo el SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

Te comento 3 opciones:

1. Primeramente trata de hacer reparación en el .Net Framework con el [**Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2698555)

[descargalo aquí.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135)

2. Si no funciona trata con estos pasos:

   - Desinstala los componentes de comunicación cliente-servidor "`Workstation components`".
   - Trata de hacer reparación en el `.Net Framework` con el [Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2698555)
   - Instala nuevamente los "`Workstation components`".
3. si no funciona lo anterior :

Desinstalar e instalar `SQL Server`, ya que esto se debe a problemas con la instalación, probablemente algun archivo corrupto.